# Getting count of distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

resulttable:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| resultSetID | projectID |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         1 |
|           1 |         2 |
|           1 |         3 |
|           2 |         1 |
|           2 |         2 |
|           3 |         1 |
|           3 |         2 |
|           3 |         3 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( projectID ) 
FROM
    resulttable
WHERE
    projectID = 3
```

... correctly returns 2. However, I want the counts of each ID without using the WHERE condition, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query is used to get all the data for the `projectId` but if you want to get a specific query data without `where` you can use having `instead`

```
SELECT projectId, COUNT( * ) 
FROM resulttable
GROUP BY projectId having projectId = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want `group by`?

```
SELECT projectId, COUNT( * ) 
FROM resulttable
GROUP BY projectID;
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query should work for you:

```
SELECT projectID, SUM(resultSetID) 
FROM resulttable
GROUP BY projectID;
```